# Conditional Rule Validation in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using [JQuery Validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation#API_Documentation). Now I want my rules to be invoked only when certain condition is satisfied, namely, I want `$("#AppSelectField").is(':hidden')` to return `false`, only then I invoke the rules.

My rules is as follow:

```
$(function() {
    $("#RequestLock").validate({
        rules: {
        FloorNum:{
        required: true,
        digits: true
        },


    },
    message: {
     FloorNum: "The floor number must be integer",

},

});
});
```

How to modify the above section to satisfy my needs? **Note I don't want to write my own custom method for `required` and `digits`.**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$(function() {
    var checkIfFieldVisible = function() {
        return !$("#AppSelectField").is(':hidden');
    };

    $("#RequestLock").validate({
        rules: {
            FloorNum: {
                required: { depends: checkIfFieldVisible },
                digits: { depends: checkIfFieldVisible }
            }, // <-- EXTRA COMMA
        },
        message: {
            FloorNum: "The floor number must be integer",
        }, // <-- EXTRA COMMA
    });
});
```

(I marked some extra commas you have on your code, as they will make IE choke)

Comment: Can we validate/not validate entire form based on certain values?. For example I have a nested form with save / submit buttons. I want to validate only on Submit. My problem is when I have the class="required" on each field as the form is very dynamic. Please help.

Comment: You don't even need the function, you can just set `depends = '#AppSelectField:visible'`