# jQuery validation built in rule with depends

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I want to use `min: 1` but I only want the rule to apply under some condition--which I think I can give in a depends function.

I want something like

```
rules: {
    field: {
        min: 1,
        depends: function(element) {
            return element.disabled == false;
        }
    }
}
```

See here for something similar https://stackoverflow.com/a/1090847/1333713

My rules above will still apply the `min` rule. How can I get it to respect my `depends`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass parameters to rules that require them, set a property named `param`. Like this,

```
rules: {
    myInputField: {
        min: {
            depends: function(element) {
                return element.disabled == false;
            },
            param: 1
        }
    }
}
```

Summary: when the validator validates `myInputField`, it will run the `depends` function to see if it should apply the `min` rule. If the `depends` function evaluates to true, the validator applies the `min` rule with the parameter `1`. This is the way to conditionally apply rules that take parameters.